# How to make arrows between the tables and make small font for the contents

Tags: tables, diagrams, ytableau

I have two questions: Firstly: How to make space between two tables and draw arrows to show the correspondence between the rows (I mean the first row in the left table corresponds the first row in the right one). Secondly: how to make small font in the third row for each table. I have posted my attempt and now it's working:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,array,subfigure,graphics,epsfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}%
\small
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{| m{3em} | m{5cm}|}
\hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Irreducibles for the maximal subgroups $G_{e}$} \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$S^{(0)}= 0 \ \ \mbox{[zero vector]}$} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$S^{(2,1)}\ $} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$
     S^{(2,1)}= \Bigg\{c_{1} e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {mathmode, boxsize=1em, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 \tiny{1} &  3 \\ 2
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{2}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {mathmode, boxsize=1em, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 \tiny{1} &  2 \\ 3
     \end{ytableau}}}
\Bigg \} 
   $} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{| m{3em} | m{5cm}|}
\hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Irreducibles for the symmetric inverse monoid $I_{4}$} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$R^{(0)}= 0 \ \ \mbox{zero vector.}$} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$R^{(2,1)}$} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$
   R^{(2,1)}= \Bigg \{
   c_{1}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 1 & 3 \\ 2
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{2}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 1 & 4 \\ 2 
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{3}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 1 & 2 \\ 3   
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{4}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 1 & 4 \\ 3  
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{5}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 2 & 4 \\ 3  
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{6}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 1 & 2 \\ 4  
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{7}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 1 & 3 \\ 4  
\end{ytableau}}}+c_{8}e_{_{\ytableausetup
     {, smalltableaux, centertableaux}\begin{ytableau}
 2 & 3 \\ 4  
\end{ytableau}}}
    \Bigg \} $} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is not compilable. Surely it need some packages (`ytableau` for instance) and fix something more.  People will be more willing to help if you can see what you have achieved so far, without having to fix a faulty example. If what you have achieved so far is just the compilation error, explain exactly what you are trying to do (what part of the code you insert) so that your minimal "working" example (MWE) is no longer working.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. it was really helpful, now it is working but I still need the answer for both question if you could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\tristrut{\rule[-1pt]{0pt}{5pt}}
\newcommand\tri[3]%
  {\raisebox{-1ex}%
    {\tiny\tabcolsep=1pt\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}%
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
     \hline
     \tristrut#1 & #2 \\
     \hline
     \tristrut#3 \\
     \cline{1-1}
     \end{tabular}%
    }%
  }

\begin{document}%
\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad\Longrightarrow\quad}c@{}}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Irreducibles for the\\
      maximal subgroups $G_{e}$
    \end{tabular}
  & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Irreducibles for the\\
      symmetric inverse monoid $I_{4}$
    \end{tabular}
  \\
    S^{(0)}= 0\quad\text{zero vector}
  & R^{(0)}= 0\quad\text{zero vector}
  \\
    S^{(2,1)}
  & R^{(2,1)}
  \\
    S^{(2,1)}= \big\{c_1 e_{\tri132} +c_2e_{\tri123} \big\}
  & \begin{aligned}[t]
      R^{(2,1)}= \big \{
      & c_1e_{\tri132} + c_2e_{\tri142} + c_3e_{\tri123} + c_4e_{\tri143} + {}\\
      & c_5e_{\tri243} + c_6e_{\tri124} + c_7e_{\tri134} + c_8e_{\tri234}\quad \big \}
     \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MalJA I've added more arrow, see my edited answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks Gernot. Really this is what I want

Comment: Sorry Gernot to bother you, I have another one but I would use \rightleftarrows (long lift right arrows), do you know what changes I should make? I attempted to replace {\quad\Longrightarrow\quad} with {\quad\rightleftarrows\quad} but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MalJA Try `\Longleftrightarrow` for a long double left-right arrow and `\Leftrightarrow` for a short double left-right arrow.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear. I want ----> and below it <---- as maps

Comment: @MalJA Try `\rightleftarrows`; you have to load the package `amssymb` for it. Did you forget the `amssymb` package? Alternatively, you can use `\rightleftharpoons`, with or without package `amssymb` (gives different symbols).

Comment: Yes! Sorry I thought I've added it. Many thanks Gernot.

Comment: Hi Gernot, thanks again for your support. Would you mind please to tell me how to make the outcome little big? what code should I play with to resize it

Comment: You can use `\scriptsize` instead of `\tiny` to increase the characters, and you can modify the definition of `\tristrut` to center the letters again; choose e.g. `\rule[-1pt]{0pt}{7pt}`. Or do you mean something different by *making the outcome little big*?